# What's holding up Dojo 1.13 on CDN?

Tags: javascript, dojo

Dojo 1.13.0 was released a couple of weeks ago and I've been waiting for it to show up at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.13.0/dojo/dojo.js.  Are Dojo releases still being published there or should I be looking elsewhere?  If that's the right place to be looking, when can I expect it to be available?

Answer (score 0):

Dojo on Google CDN it is still not available. The latest version on CDN is 1.12.2.

I suggest you to open a ticket to Dojo and notify them, but usually the take care about update on CDN after few days of their release on GitHub.

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/